# Confused by Malus theorem in optics

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I am a bit confused about Malus theorem in optics ,as shown below : we consider a punctual light wave source  , two light rays SB and SA , and two mirrors M1 and M2 placed respectively orthogonal to the bissectors of the angles (SA,Uz) and (SB,Uz), in order to make the reflected rays colinear to Uz .

By malus theorem : φ(A)=φ(C) mod 2pi

Using the relation between the optical path and the phase difference :

φ(C)-φ(A)= (2pi/λ)*(nd) ; n is the refractive index of the milieu

Which is contradictory to Mallus theorem . Can anyone help me ? Thanks .[image]

Comment: What is the point $C$ and why do you think $\phi(A)=\phi(C) \rm{mod}(2\pi)$; what does it have to do with Malus' theorem? (please use mathjax)

Comment: Hi , φ(A) means the phase of the ray at A , and malus theorem states that wave fronts are othogonal to the rays , and as A and C are from the same orthogonal plane then they have the same phase .

Comment: Malus theorem does NOT say that "wave fronts are orthogonal to the rays", this is just wrong. Think of a coherent point source  whose illumination is split into two by a screen whose plane contains the source. On one side you capture the light and pass it through a 10,000km long fiber after which you put it to the other side. Obviously the rays from the  fiber will have nothing to do with what is going on the other side, wavefronts or rays. Malus theorem is true only if it is restricted to a sufficiently small (i.e., narrow) but finite pencil of rays.

Comment: Hi , yes I do agree with you , I was not specific in my first comment , but the example above still hold , because we are dealing with small and only two rays , that both had one reflection so  malus theorem holds which gives a contradiction . What is your point about that ?